# Can I define a set containing elements from different vectorial spaces?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Recently I was solving some problems and I ended up with a certain problem that I cant yet understand because of the sets that it proposes. The problem goes like this.

---

Let be $A\subset \Bbb R^p$ An open set, and $B\subset \Bbb R^n$. Lets define the following sets

---

a) A+B={ x+y$\in \Bbb R^p$ | $x\in A$ and $y\in B$}

---

b) If n=1, AB={ xy$\in R$ | $x\in A$ and $y\in B$}

---

c) If $A\subset \Bbb R$, E={ (x,y)$\in \Bbb R^2$ | x$\in A$}

---

Determine which of the previuos sets are open sets.

---

And that is the problem, but my concern is that, can it be possible to define such kinds of sets?, becuase for example in a) for me it seems that the elements of the set are defined by the addition of elements from diferent vectorial spaces, and I dont understand if it is posible or not. I would appreciate any explanations about this in order for me to undestand and solve this problem.

Comment: for $(a)$ are you given that $p \geq n$?

Comment: where is $y$ in (c)?

Comment: Thats the problem, that is everything that it says. And I also asked myself that, thats why I dont understands whats happening.

Comment: Do you mean r=p=1? Or why 14?

Comment: Yeah, I did. Im sorry. I think in that case, the question makes total sense. Otherwise, it seems to me that $(a)$ is poorly defined, although it would make sense if $p \geq n$ and $x+y$ is just co-ordinate wise addition. Perhaps in (c) it is safe to assume that $y$ is an arbitrary point in $\mathbb R$, and forget about $B$ there.

Comment: But what about the set b), should I asume that also p=1? becuase the product ends on $\Bbb R$. And when you refer to me to consider p>n, is for taking the elements from B to be those in which there can be any kind of numbers until N, and the rest to be cero until p?

Comment: *sigh* I suppose so. May I ask who gave you these problems, or where you found them?

Comment: Is from a list of exercises that were given to me by my calculus teacher.